# Draw Circle with connected line responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

i wanted to create a circle with connected Line responsive design

[image]

when i resize the screen

[image]

But my expectation would be like this can anyone help me?

[image]

here is my code of HTML and CSS:

```html
<html>
<style>
li {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  background: #1F3864;
  margin: 0 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

li::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: 0.2em;
  background: #1F3864;
  z-index: -1;
}
li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<ul>
  <li> M1 </li>
  <li> M2 </li>
  <li> M3 </li>
  <li> M4 </li>
  <li> M5 </li>
  <li> M6 </li>
  <li> M7 </li>
  <li> M8 </li>
  <li> M9 </li>
  <li> M10 </li>
  <li> M11 </li>
</ul>
</html>
```

forget to inform one thing its dynamic data.
for Example <li *ngFor="let a of array">

Comment: Please add an example of the code you have tried already. People are happy to help but SO isn’t an ab initio coding service. This link should help you add a snippet that we can run https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: okay let me add that code here

Comment: I don't think what you want can be achieved using CSS alone, because CSS does not know anything about the overflow/line breaks.

Comment: then what do we need to use? u mean javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grid to change the positioning of elements without having to change the HTML.

This snippet takes the basic idea from the code in the question of using a pseudo element to draw a line to the next element.

With a media query it changes the grid layout to have fewer items in a row and 'swivels' this line round for some edge elements.

Of course you will want to alter the dimensions of things and the media break points to suit your particular use case. This snippet breaks at 600px width and uses vw as the unit so that things are responsive.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circles {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  --cols: 11;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
  --gap: 4vw;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.circles>* {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.circles>*::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--gap);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: navy;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 100%;
}

.circles>*:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .circles {
    --cols: 5;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(5)::after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: var(--gap);
    width: 1px;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 5;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(6)::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(8) {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(9) {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(10) {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .circles>*:nth-child(11)::after {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    width: 1px;
    height: var(--gap);
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="circles">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is just to give the idea. Obviously more would need to be included to account for a different number of circles.

Comment: Thanks for the response. only one doubt i have. i am using dynamic <li> can u suggest anything. bcz u mention static value for child element in media query

Comment: Do you mean your number of lis can change dynamically?

Comment: Yes. its dynamic