# Draw dynamic Circle with connected line responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

i wanted to create a circle with connected Line responsive design

[image]

when i resize the screen

[image]

But my expectation would be like this can anyone help me?

[image]

here is my code of HTML and CSS:

```html
<html>
<style>
li {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  background: #1F3864;
  margin: 0 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

li::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: 0.2em;
  background: #1F3864;
  z-index: -1;
}
li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<ul>
  <li> M1 </li>
  <li> M2 </li>
  <li> M3 </li>
  <li> M4 </li>
  <li> M5 </li>
  <li> M6 </li>
  <li> M7 </li>
  <li> M8 </li>
  <li> M9 </li>
  <li> M10 </li>
  <li> M11 </li>
</ul>
</html>
```

its dynamic data using angular.
for Example

```
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let a of listOfCircle"> {{a.code}} </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I think the layout you want to achieve cannot be done with CSS alone.

Comment: Can you say what break points are wanted? For example if the viewport is 600px wide, how many circles do you want per line?

Comment: @Terry then can suggest or give a example for that

Comment: @AHaworth each line max 10 for big screen each line 5 for small screen.but circle cout some time 13 some time i can be 20

Comment: You can do this with just CSS as you know the breakpoint. The image in your question shows 4 on a row, does this mean you have more than one media width breakpoint?

Comment: Can u give example @AHaworth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what break points you want (ie at what width you want to have what number of columns) this can be done in pure CSS.

This snippet has two sets. The first is for widths >600px and the second for widths <=600px with 10 columns per row in the first set and 5 columns per row in the second set.

It uses a grid and reverses the order of columns occupied by alternate rows using the CSS nth-child facility.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 90vw;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .circles {
      width: 100%;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
      --gap: 4vw;
      gap: var(--gap);
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
    }
    
    .circles>* {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: navy;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      display inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .circles>*::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: var(--gap);
      height: 1px;
      background-color: navy;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      left: 100%;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .circles {
        --cols: 10;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-10)::after {
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        height: var(--gap);
        width: 1px;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-9) {
        grid-column: 10;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-9)::after {
        display: none;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-8) {
        grid-column: 9;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-7) {
        grid-column: 8;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-6) {
        grid-column: 7;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-5) {
        grid-column: 6;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-4) {
        grid-column: 5;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-3) {
        grid-column: 4;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-2) {
        grid-column: 3;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-1) {
        grid-column: 2;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n) {
        grid-column: 1;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-8):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-7):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-6):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-5):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-4):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-3):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-2):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n-1):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n):last-child::after {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(20n+1)::before {
        display: inline-block;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        width: 1px;
        height: var(--gap);
        top: 0;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background-color: navy;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .circles {
        --cols: 5;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-5)::after {
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        height: var(--gap);
        width: 1px;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-4) {
        grid-column: 5;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-4)::after {
        display: none;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-3) {
        grid-column: 4;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-2) {
        grid-column: 3;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-1) {
        grid-column: 2;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n) {
        grid-column: 1;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-3):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-2):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n-1):last-child::after,
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n):last-child::after {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .circles>*:nth-child(10n+1)::before {
        display: inline-block;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        width: 1px;
        height: var(--gap);
        top: 0;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background-color: navy;
      }
    }
    
    .circles>*:first-child::before,
    .circles>*:last-child::after {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="circles">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
      <li>21</li>
      <li>22</li>
      <li>23</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: this answer builds on and partly generalises the answer to the question at [Draw Circle with connected line responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912233/draw-circle-with-connected-line-responsive/70913077?noredirect=1#comment125376124_70913077) which had more specific, i.e. limiting, conditions.

Comment: thanks for ur answer.its working fine. but when we have only 2 rows that time last circle is not connecting . pls check and can u correct that pls

Comment: The problem was the removal of the after pseudo element on the final element when there were an exact number of full rows. A test for this has been added at the end of the CSS. It should work OK now.

Comment: i think u dont get it.kindly remove last 4 li element then see the issue.Bcz last circle is not connecting

Comment: I added more conditions to deal with the last element being in a reversed row. Have to say although the logic is not hard the CSS gets lengthy so if it were my system I'd probably use JS to create the stylesheet rather than code the CSS by hand. However, for this two break point situation it is manageable.

Comment: Thanks. Its Working fine. i can understood ur feelings. if u post "how to achieve in JavaScript?", that will be more helpful for me as well as others.